# How to update database by attaching model to DataContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-sql

I am building a web site using MVC 3 Framework.I have a Linq to SQL DataContext to handle data access.According to what I've learned you can use a post method to get the form information when a user submits a form and MVC frmaework can map the data to a model object.
something like this :

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Edit(Entity model)
```

But I have problem with attaching this model object to the data context object here's what I am doing :

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Edit(Entity model)
    {

        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _dataContext.Attach(model);
            _dataContext.SubmitChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View("Edit", model);
    }
```

But nothing happens.What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `_dataContext` doesn't know that your entity has been changed.
So you would have to use the [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548778.aspx) that sets modified as true:

```
_dataContext.Attach(model, true);
```

Comment: I tried this approach but it says that the entity should have a version field.

Comment: Does you `Entity` have a [version key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386957.aspx) defined? Another approach is to retrieve the original entity from the context, updating it with your changes (from `model`) and then `SubmitChanges`.

Comment: I have tried the original approach either.the problems are : first I have to load the original version into datacontext and second when I try to attach the updated version it gives me an error that says there's already an object with the same key in the context (the original one)

Comment: In this case you shouldn't attach the updated version but just copy their properties to the original one: `myOriginal.Name = model.Name`